# Why rotated UILabel can not be render?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uilabel

My UILabel was rotated like this:

```
currentLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(135 / 180 * M_PI);
```

And I make an UILabel as a subview of imgViewToSave(which is an UIImageView), just save it as an Image at last:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgViewToSave.bounds.size, imgViewToSave.opaque, 0.0);
[imgViewToSave.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

But when the image was saved to Photo, I can not see the UILabel who has been rotated, If I do not rotate the UILabel, the code works fine and UILabel will show in the image.

So, why rotated UILabel can not be render?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are just rendering the `layer` of the image view. The image view's subviews have their own layers.

Use `addSublayer` instead of `addSubview` and try again.

Also you should check if it looks as expected with the rotation on screen first.
Also maybe you have to make sure that the rect in which you draw is big enough to enclose all of the rendered objects, including the rotated label.

Comment: I have tried as [imgViewToSave.layer addSublayer:currentLabel.layer]; but it still failed. And I found that if the angle of rotation is small, it will show, if it is big, it will not show.

Comment: Maybe you have to increase the rect to include all of the rotated label?